# Batch debug attribute in web.config

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me what exactly the batch debug option in web.config (attribute) does? I can tell it debugs in batches ( >1) but I cannot find anymore background info on this setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx

Optional Boolean attribute.

Indicates whether batching is supported.

If True, eliminates the delay caused by the compilation required when you access a file for the first time. When this attribute is set to True, ASP.NET precompiles all the uncompiled files in a batch mode, which causes an even longer delay the first time the files are compiled. However, after this initial delay, the compilation delay is eliminated on subsequent access of the file.

The default is True.